# Issues with pdf Export and Plot including Frame

Tags: export

I encountered an issue with `Export` when exporting to .pdf a graphic similar to

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}, Frame -> True]
Export["someFile.pdf", %]
```

Visualization in the frondend is normal but in the exported .pdf the frame ticks are missing.

[image]

I am on OS X 10.11.6 and using Mathematica 11.1.1.0. Any other plot function I tried (such as `ListPlot`) and other formats but with the expression from above (e.g. .png) work fine.

Comment: no problem on Windows 10 and Linux.

Comment: If you add FrameTicks->True it will also work on MacOSX.

Comment: The same in Linux (Ubuntu 17.10) with Mathematica 11.1.1.0.

Comment: I also observe the same problem. Windows 10 with Mathematica 11.2.0.0. The problem is not persistent as it only shows up for certain plots. I have yet to find the pattern that triggers the problem yet.

Comment: same problem for Ubuntu 17.10 with Mathematica 10.0 ;(

Comment: Same problem in Win 10, Mathematica 11! In my case two plots combined with `Show[]`.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO It should be marked as a bug. For example the following gives a bug:

```
g = Framed@Plot[Sin[x], {x, -3, 3}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameTicks -> {Automatic, Automatic}]
Export["test.pdf", g]
```

[image: frame ticks missing]

Only workaround I found was to set the tick labels explicitly:

```
g = Framed@
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, -3, 3}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameTicks -> {Range[-1, 1, 1], Range[-1, 1, 0.25]}]
```

[image: frame ticks present]

Problem is present on: `"11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"`

Problem is not there on: `"11.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 18, 2017)"`

Sometimes if I change something it works once properly but if I export the same object again it no longer works until I change something again.

Bugreport filled.

**Edit**

I have real trouble reporducing the error with minimal notebooks. It keeps happening with complicated figures reproducably. Meanwhile I figured out, that it already helps, if you wrap with `Show[#,FrameTicks->Automatic]&`.

Comment: I was able to make ticks show with just `FrameTicks->Automatic` as you mention. This way you don't need to calculate explicit values for them.

Comment: I just found that by explicitly assign the format "PDF" to `Export` the ticks won't disappear in MMA 11.3. Don't know if that's a general solution.